# How do I set an empty view for ListViews in an activity with multiple ListViews?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I have 3 lists stacked on top of each other in a single Activity, and I would like to set empty views for each of them. I have tried setting the empty view to both dynamically created views and views defined in the layout, but either way all it seems to do when the list is empty is collapse it to 0 height, regardless of the fact that I have set the minimum height for each list to 60px.

This is the xml definition for the empty view

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:text="@string/empty_text"
        />

mListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
```

and this is how I programmatically created the text view.

```
mEmptyView = new TextView(this);
mEmptyView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
mEmptyView.setText(R.string.empty_text);

mListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyView);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My bad, this was pretty silly on my part :P  I was under the rather ludicrous impression that if I put a TextView somewhere randomly in the xml layout and then set it as the empty view for a list, it would magically disappear and then reappear in the list when the list was empty. I guess I thought that the list would add it as a row in the list when it's adapter was empty. In the unlikely even that someone else decides to try something similarly ludicrous and wonders what's going on, I will post the full version of my original layout as well as the solution.

The code I used to set the empty view was the standard:

```
mListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

however my original layout looked like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/drafts"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/drafts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="60sp"
        />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/finished"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/finished"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:minHeight="60px"
        />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/uploaded"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/uploaded"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="60sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:text="DUDE WHERE'S MY CAR?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

While my listviews have a minHeight of 60sp, when the list was empty the height seemingly went to 0. As well, I noticed that the TextView was visible below all three of my lists so it did not seem to be "disappearing" and reappearing as a row in my list. How disappointing! In a gross oversight on my part, for testing I set the view as the emptyView for my second list only, ensured that my first and second lists were empty, and populated the third list. My first list had its min-height, my second shrank to 0, my third list was correctly populated, and my empty view appeared below it. I did not try populating the second list, and thus never realized that the empty view would subsequently disappear.

Finally after spending an hour more playing around with dynamically generated empty views and whatnot, I left it for a day and came back tonight and tested populating the second list. Voila, the empty view disappeared and the lightbulb went on. I quickly tested moving the empty view below the second list and above the third list, and of course, it worked perfectly!

Here is the new working layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/drafts"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/drafts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/finished"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/finished"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:minHeight="60px"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:text="DUDE WHERE'S MY CAR?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/uploaded"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/uploaded"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Long answer, probably just talking to myself, but whatever - asked the question, figured it out, and I never seem to be able to answer anybody else's questions on here so I might as well answer my own :)