# setEmptyView Android listview

Tags: android, listview

hello in my application contain listview.listview contain footer which contain next button whan user press next button listview adapter are refreshed and new question are populated using notify data set changed method.but i want to set a message when data is empty which are read from a json file(Dynamic json file comming from the server).
i used setEmptyView method but it will hide listview and my footer also hide so user can not move to next set of question.
 and i am not extending listview. extends a custom baseadapter please guide me i am new in android

**

> Update:-

**
i solved it using creating textview addview into xml and return customeview. my getview method shown below.any other way can i do this. can this code may impact on the app performance. beacause i am inflecting another view please guide me

```
@Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        if(itemDetailarraylist.size()==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return itemDetailarraylist.size();
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        if (itemDetailarraylist.size() == 0) {
            TextView message = new TextView(context);
            message.setText("No Data Found on This Section");
            message.setTextSize(20);
            message.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    (int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nodatafound_message,null);
            ((LinearLayout)convertView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ((LinearLayout)convertView).addView(message);
            return convertView;
        } else {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {------}}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Update:-

** i solved it using creating textview addview into xml and return customeview. my getview method shown below.any other way can i do this. can this code may impact on the app performance. beacause i am inflecting another view please guide me

@Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        if(itemDetailarraylist.size()==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return itemDetailarraylist.size();
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        if (itemDetailarraylist.size() == 0) {
            TextView message = new TextView(context);
            message.setText("No Data Found on This Section");
            message.setTextSize(20);
            message.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    (int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nodatafound_message,null);
            ((LinearLayout)convertView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ((LinearLayout)convertView).addView(message);
            return convertView;
        } else {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {------}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see this link

[How do I set an empty view for ListViews in an activity with multiple ListViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425017/how-do-i-set-an-empty-view-for-listviews-in-an-activity-with-multiple-listviews)

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/empty_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60px"
android:text="@string/empty_text"
/>

mListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
```

Comment: but setEmptyView hide the listview so i can not move to the next set of question so i solve it using check size of my data arraylist and if it's zero than inflate the custom view